# how can i make my nodejs socket app visible from outside azure VM

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io

I am running a nodejs socket IO on my Azure VM using the node server.js command on port 4000, and opened the port. but i noticed i can call the socket via [a websocket tester in the VM](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) but not outside the VM, via the IP address. Please what is the issue, and how can i make my socket server visible outside my azure VM

Comment: Can you have an inbound rule in your subnet or VM NSG to allow port 4000 ?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT what do you mean ?

Comment: on the portal, you can find the network security group associated to the VM subnet or network interface in the virtual machine --networking blade.

Comment: I am not really a network guy, but please can we chat on skype or somwhere so i can follow you step by step

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic) to add a inbound rule to allow port 4000, or you can share the screenshot about the nsg in your side.

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT, is this a common issue with nodejs socketio servers ?

Comment: I am not sure, just verify this issue. NSG is just like firewall if you want to access the Azure VM outside of Azure or VM.

Comment: We have done as the link said, but issues still exist. I am actually running the node app via forever and not iis, could this the the issue